# how to access from app component to my react reusable table cell data

Tags: reactjs, reusability

I've created a table component so I can reuse it in different part on my project, as I need it to be more flexible and also for a better practic for on how to do that
**My Goal:** Inside my **Friends component** I'm trying to capture on what cell the use clicked.

**Friends component**

```
const Friends = () => {


    // My goal is to get the the information about the clickedcell here


    const theadData = ["Name", "Email", "Date"];

    const tbodyData = [
        {
            id: "1",
            items: ["Peter", "peter@email.com", "01/01/2021"],
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            items: ["Foo", "foo@email.com", "12/24/2020"],
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            items: ["bar", "bar@email.com", "12/01/2020"],
        },
    ];
    return(
      <div>
        <Table theadData={theadData}
          tbodyData={tbodyData} />
      </div>
    )
}

export default Friends;
```

**Table Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import TableHeaderItem from './tableHead'
import TableRow from './tableRow'

const Table = ({theadData, tbodyData}) => {
  

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {
            theadData.map(headerTitle => {
             return <TableHeaderItem
                      key={headerTitle}
                      item={headerTitle} />
            })
          }
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {
              tbodyData.map(row => {
                console.log("rowID", row.id)
                return <TableRow
                        onRowClicked={() => console.log('user clicked on row #', row.id)}
                        key={row.id}
                        rowData={row.items} />
              })
          }

      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

export default Table
```

**TableRow component**

```
import TableCell from './tableCell'


const TableRow = ({ rowData, onRowClicked, onCellClick}) => {

  return(
      <tr
        onClick={onRowClicked} >
        {
          
          rowData.map(cell => {
            return (
              <TableCell
                key={cell}
                cellData={cell}

                onCellClicked={()=>console.log('user cliecked on cell name',cell)}
          
                />)})
        }
      </tr>
  )
}

export default TableRow;
```

**TabelCell component**

```
const TableCell = ({   cellData, onCellClicked}) => {

  return (
      <td
        onClick={onCellClicked}>{cellData}</td>
  )
}

export default TableCell;
```

Comment: There are 2 ways: The first way is to use props. Here you have to use 4 steps to send click signal to Friends component from TableCell component. The second way is to use redux-saga module: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html. redux-saga is a global function in react. You can use action to catch click event in any component.

Comment: Which way do you need to use in your app?

Comment: Ideally, I think I'd prefer to have access to it as a Table prop and then access to it from my Friends component or any other component that I'll reuse this Table component.

Is that not the right way to do it?

Comment: Props can go through parent and children components. Will I add solution for multi step props?

Comment: If you can, because I don't seem to get the result I want. I was trying to do onClick for each cell with the data I'm printing there. If I understand correctly, props will be more easy to reuse it?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the redux-saga, so to be honest I'll have to read about it and see how it's working there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229461/discussion-between-peter-and-artem-medianyk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friends component

```
const Friends = () => {


    // My goal is to get the the information about the clickedcell here


    const theadData = ["Name", "Email", "Date"];

    const tbodyData = [
        {
            id: "1",
            items: ["Peter", "peter@email.com", "01/01/2021"],
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            items: ["Foo", "foo@email.com", "12/24/2020"],
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            items: ["bar", "bar@email.com", "12/01/2020"],
        },
    ];

    const onFriendClicked = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target);
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <Table theadData={theadData}
          tbodyData={tbodyData}
          onTableClicked={onFriendClicked}
        />
      </div>
    )
}

export default Friends;
```

Table Component

```
import React from 'react'
import TableHeaderItem from './tableHead'
import TableRow from './tableRow'

const Table = ({theadData, tbodyData, onTableClicked}) => {
  

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {
            theadData.map(headerTitle => {
             return <TableHeaderItem
                      key={headerTitle}
                      item={headerTitle} />
            })
          }
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {
              tbodyData.map(row => {
                console.log("rowID", row.id)
                return <TableRow
                        onRowClicked={onTableClicked}
                        key={row.id}
                        rowData={row.items} />
              })
          }

      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

export default Table
```

TableRow component

```
import TableCell from './tableCell'


const TableRow = ({ rowData, onRowClicked}) => {

  return(
      <tr
        onClick={onRowClicked} >
        {
          
          rowData.map(cell => {
            return (
              <TableCell
                key={cell}
                cellData={cell}

                onCellClicked={onRowClicked}
          
                />)})
        }
      </tr>
  )
}

export default TableRow;
```

TabelCell component

```
const TableCell = ({   cellData, onCellClicked}) => {

  return (
      <td
        onClick={onCellClicked}>{cellData}</td>
  )
}

export default TableCell;
```

Comment: Thank you! that's working. I can't believe I miss that as a prop..

Comment: Artem, ideally I should try to use hooks for that?

Comment: what do you mean? about saga?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would declare a function that takes some data parameter and returns a function and use that as your click handler. You would declare it where you put your comment and pass it down as props.

This leverages the concept of closures to make each callback unique to the row that was clicked.

Ex:

```
const Friends = () => {


    // My goal is to get the the information about the clickedcell here
    const onRowClicked = rowData => () => {
      // do something with rowData
    }
    // the return value of this function call 
    // is the click handler with the row data as closure
    <SomeComponentDownstream onClick={onRowClicked(row.data)} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood correctly you want to get cell clicked cell data from another Route or App.js ( where combined all router )

1. use Redux to store in global state
2. use localStorage to store in memory of browser